# Configure sonar for two databases

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I'm trying to integrate Sonar with Jenkins installation. In my Jenkins I have two projects : a Php project and a Java project. I have also two databases one for each projet : sonar_ezpublish and sonar_genolims.

I installed SonarQube 5.6 and sonnar runner 3.0.3. 
How could I configure my sonar.properties for the two databases ?

My conf for the first database :

```
sonar.jdbc.username=username
sonar.jdbc.password=password

#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# If you don't use the schema named "public", please refer to http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5000
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar_ezpublish
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the fact that there doesn't seem to be a good reason to maintain a SonarQube instance per project...

Configure two SonarQube instances at the global level. You should then be able to specify which instance to use in each analysis.

Comment: thanks for your rapid answer. By configuring two instances, you mean that I have to download another sonarQube and make it run on the port 9001 for example ? Sorry for the stupid question, I start with sonarQube.

Comment: @TeddyKossoko it sounds like you have bigger/more complex questions than are really appropriate to the StackOverflow format. I suggest you start a new thread in the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube)